# load table data from mysql into one input field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on trying to input data from mysql into one field, below is mysql code: what I'm trying to do is have all the data from $row['db_numbers']; load into the

```
<input type="text" name="db_numbers" values="<?php echo $row['db_numbers'];?>
```

but it makes double the fields

were i end up with multiple db_number fields, I only want one.

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM sms_numbers  WHERE `db_user` ='".$user_name."'";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die("<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.<br />Query: ".$query."<br />Error: (".mysql_errno().") ".mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
   $group_sms = $row['db_numbers'];
  }         
?>
```

Comment: Change `while` to `if`..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?php
         $query = "SELECT * FROM sms_numbers  WHERE `db_user` ='".$user_name."'";
         $result = mysql_query($query) or die("<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.<br />Query: ".$query."<br />Error: (".mysql_errno().") ".mysql_error());
         WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            $group_sms .= $row['db_numbers'];
         }
    ?>
```

And then:

```
     <input type="text" name="db_numbers" values="<?php echo $group_sms;?>">
```

Notice the '.=' in the while loop. It concatenates the numbers. Maybe add some spaces between them if you want ('. " "')?

```
    WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
       $group_sms .= $row['db_numbers'] . " ";
    }
```

Then echo the $group_sms variable since that contains all the db_numbers.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you are directly returning `$row['db_numbers']` after querying the DB, then you can just print the `$group_sms` in the `<input />` tag.

So my opinion would be:
 - either `return $row` after querying the DB
 - or directly use `$group_sms` in `<input />` tag

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to create an input element containing the value from a single field in the database there is no need for looping, use this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT db_numbers FROM sms_numbers WHERE username = '$user_name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$value = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$db_numbers = $value->id;
?>
```

If you have multiple values that you want to concatenate or sum you could do that directly in the query and use the same code otherwise:

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(db_numbers SEPARATOR '') AS db_numbers FROM sms_numbers WHERE username = '$user_name'";
$sql = "SELECT SUM(db_numbers) AS db_numbers FROM sms_numbers WHERE username = '$user_name'";
```

Then use this to output:

```
<input type="text" name="db_numbers" values="<?php echo $db_numbers;?>
```